# Isometric isomorphism of an infinite dimensional vector space $V$ and its double dual.

Tags: functional-analysis

I recently proved that every Hilbert space is reflexive (isomorphic to its double dual) which is a really nice structure theorem that had more or less two essential ingredients:

1. The canonical mapping $g_{x} f :=f(x)$ is an isometry.
2. The Riesz Representation theorem.

However, I was reading an exposition, that can be found [here](http://www.thebookshelf.auckland.ac.nz/docs/Maths/PDF/mathschron008-003.pdf), showing the same result (in this case, there exists a map $f:A \to B$ that is a group isomorphism and a homeomorphism) for any locally compact Hausdorff (abelian) topological space (a bit of a mouthful.)

I can see that the aforementioned theorem does not apply since a topological vector space is [locally compact iff it is finite dimensional](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/).

My question: are there similar restrictions on infinite dimensional vector spaces that can allow us to make a similar statement of the following nature: 
A topological vector space $V$ (I would be happy with just Banach as well) is isometrically isomorphic to $V^{**}$ if ____.

I know that if $V$ is seperable with nonseperable $V^{*}$, the theorem cannot hold, so this is a start.

As an aside, is there a convenient language to talk about this?

Comment: What do you mean by topologically isomorphic ? Isomorphic in the category of topological spaces ?

Comment: Sorry, that was kind of made up terminology. There exists a map $f:A \to B$ that is both a group homomorphism and a homeomorphism.

Comment: I suppose that every isometric isomorphism is also a homeomorphism since $\|Tx\|=\|X\|$ and is thus bounded, so it is continuous (with the same argument to be made for its inverse image.)

Comment: I think this helps : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space

Comment: There are tons of non-separable Banach spaces that are reflexive. A Hausdorff locally convex space is reflexive if and only if its bounded subsets are relatively weakly compact and it is quasibarrelled [it is then in fact barrelled]. If the canonical isomorphism is then an isometry if the space isn't Banach depends on what you are willing to call isometry.

Comment: That was a foolish claim of mine. I don't know what the term barrelled means, but I'll be sure to take a look at the literature. Thanks. An if and only if is even better than what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Fischer Answered this question in my comments:

> "A Hausdorff locally convex space is reflexive if and only if its
>   bounded subsets are relatively weakly compact and it is quasibarrelled
>   [it is then in fact barrelled]. If the canonical isomorphism is then
>   an isometry if the space isn't Banach depends on what you are willing
>   to call isometry."